# Odata4j 0.7 Client Expected Status Missing NOT_FOUND

Tags: client-side, odata4j

Does anyone know why the Odata4j 0.7.0 client have updated expected response status? For more details you can refer to the issue raised on following link;

https://code.google.com/p/odata4j/issues/detail?id=264

Comment: This was because I was trying to use it with Odata4j version 0.6.0 and hence it was failing.